# Determine the image of $f$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, proof-writing

I am given the following equation:

$$
f(n) = \begin{cases} n+3 & n\text{ even} \\
         2(n-1) & n\text{ odd}
\end{cases}
$$

Determine the image of $f$ (meaning the image $f(\mathbb{Z})$ of the entire domain $\mathbb{Z}$) and prove that the answer is correct)

I am not entirely sure what is meant by image and proving the answer is correct.

Comment: @Masacroso If that is true, then you should be able to find me an $n$ such that $f(n) = 2$.

Comment: @Arthur right... good eye.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image of a function is the set of values that it meets. For example, if $g(n)=n^2$ and the domain of $g$ is $\Bbb Z$, then the image of $g$ is the set of perfect squares.

So: if $n$ is even, how is $n+3$? Is there any number of this kind that can't be $n+3$? If $n$ is odd, how is $2(n-1)$? Perhaps you are thinking "even", but can *any* even number be expressed as $2(n-1)$ for odd $n$? For example: $6$? $10$? $14$?